# '#' Operator in String

Tags: c#, string

I have a piece of code and I'm trying to figure out what the `hash(#)` inside the string.
Following is the piece of code.

```
var key = string.Format( "{0}#{1}#{2}", value1, value2, value3);

if ( !instance.Map.ContainsKey( key ) )
{
   throw new Exception("Dear Customer, your  order cant be identified.");
}
```

I don't think I have ever used `#` in `C#`

if I did not provide `value3` it still finds the key.Therefore I thought that the # means compulsory or part of this.

Comment: What output you are getting..??

Comment: It means character will appear between the 3 values that is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nothing, they will just be in the output string suppose you have:

```
var key = string.Format("{0}#{1}#{2}", 1, 2, 3);
```

Your output string would be:

```
1#2#3
```

It (`#`) would be used as a symbol in the resultant string.

Comment: @user1702369, What is there to understand ? you can have any symbol instead of `#`, you can have `-` anything, it would be in the resultant string. Its not doing anything

Comment: @user1702369 You may not have used # in c# before, but your not really using it here. Your output is in (" ") therefore anything between "" will come out in your output, hense # is doing nothing to cause you any harm.

Comment: @user1702369, from your edited comment, i believe this key with symbole `#` is used in a dictionary `articlesMap`. They key consits of three values separated by `#` symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Here developer wants to attach `#` with this string between the values.There is no special purpose of # in C# in this code so dont confuse yourself due to this `#`.Your output can be like this

```
int value1= 1;
int value1= 1;
int value1= 1;
var key = string.Format( "{0}#{1}#{2}", value1, value2, value3);

Output:1#1#1
```

So it is just a literal nothing special.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a part of the literal output, it's not interpreted as anything special.

If you tested this you would immediately see that each parameter (`{n}`) is replaced with the appropriate value specified in the parameter argument array, and that `#` remains as it stands - verbatim output.